# Upper and lower limit problem in Beamer with \onslide

Tags: latex, beamer

I need the following with `\onslide`

[image]

I have used the following Latex code

```
$\onslide<1->{\left[}\onslide<2->{\dfrac{e^{-st}}{s^2+1}}\onslide<3->{\left(-s\sin t - \cos t\right)}\onslide<4->{\right]_0^{\pi}}$
```

and its output is as follows

[image]

Comment: And just for completeness because the display of close voters is misleading: I voted to migrate the question, not to close. The question is well written and includes all necessary information. It makes no sense to close it as "needs details or clarity", because it has all details and is totally clear.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use fixed size parenthesis:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    

    
\begin{frame}
$
\onslide+<1->{\bigg[}\onslide+<2->{\dfrac{e^{-st}}{s^2+1}}\onslide+<3->{\left(-s\sin t - \cos t\right)}\onslide+<4->{\bigg]_0^{\pi}}
$
\end{frame}   
  

  
\end{document}
```

[image]